# Grafana OAuth Authentication with WSO2

Tags: authentication, oauth, wso2, grafana

I use WSO2 as an identity server to log in / log out of an application. To analyze some data, I want to use Grafana's dashboards.

I want to perform OAuth Authentication on grafana using WSO2.
I want to access Grafana using the WSO2 user credentials which I also use to access my application.

Is it possible?

Comment: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/auth/generic-oauth/

Answer (score 0):

Grafana uses the standard openid connect approch. So you can easily connect Grafana with OAuth/OpenID connect inbound protocol. You can create a OpenID connect App is WSO2 Identity Server side and get client id and secrets and configure them in Grafana side. So you can login to Grafana using WSo2 Identity Server side.

Refer : https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/configuring-oauth2-openid-connect-single-sign-on/

You can find WSO2 Identity Server openID connect endpoints from the discovery endpoint:
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/openid-connect-discovery/#openid-connect-discovery